# Jump call from one dahdi channel to other

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

Hi I will describe as best I can.

I am using Asterisk 1.4 with DAHDI 2.4. We have merged two PRI lines i.e now we have 60 lines on one span.

I want to jump call from one channel to other, i.e. I call is received on channel no. 3 of dahdi then I want to switch this call to channel number 32 i.e. on the second number(not for all, only for some specific cases).

I use `Dial(DAHDI/G1)` to dial the free channel available from last, but it does not work

Comment: please reply for this problem 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192639/unable-to-create-channel-of-type-dahdi-cause-17-user-busy

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 groups and dial to dahdi/g2.

See default chan_dahdi.conf.sample for examples.
You also able put some channels to more then 1 groups(for example to group 0 all and to group1 only pri span 1)

Comment: Ya I have create two group but still it give the same error, hangup cause 21