# Unable to create channel of type 'DAHDI' (cause 17 - User busy)

Tags: asterisk

I have 6 Red FXO with TDM2400p in my PC. I have install asterisk and dahdi driver.
Scenario is

jitsi-----> asterisk server-----> analog PBX ----> landline phone

I configured this scenario as follow

in chan_dahdi.conf file

```
; General options
[channels]
usecallerid=yes
hidecallerid=no
callwaiting=yes
threewaycalling=yes 
transfer=yes
echocancel=yes
echocancelwhenbridged=yes
rxgain=0.0 
txgain=0.0
;FXO Modules
group=2
echocancel=yes
signalling=fxs_ks
context=Incoming
channel=1-20
```

After loading module in astrisk giving o/p below

```
module load chan_dahdi.so
Loaded chan_dahdi.so
== Parsing '/etc/asterisk/chan_dahdi.conf':   == Found
== Parsing '/etc/asterisk/users.conf':   == Found
-- Registered channel 1, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 2, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 3, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 4, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 5, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 6, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 7, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 8, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 9, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 10, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 11, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 12, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 13, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 14, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 15, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 16, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 17, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 18, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 19, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Registered channel 20, FXS Kewlstart signalling
-- Automatically generated pseudo channel
[Nov  2 14:38:50] WARNING[1886]: chan_dahdi.c:17278 process_dahdi: Ignoring any changes to 'userbase' (on reload) at line 23.
[Nov  2 14:38:50] WARNING[1886]: chan_dahdi.c:17278 process_dahdi: Ignoring any changes to 'vmsecret' (on reload) at line 31.
[Nov  2 14:38:50] WARNING[1886]: chan_dahdi.c:17278 process_dahdi: Ignoring any changes to 'hassip' (on reload) at line 35.
[Nov  2 14:38:50] WARNING[1886]: chan_dahdi.c:17278 process_dahdi: Ignoring any changes to 'hasiax' (on reload) at line 39.
[Nov  2 14:38:50] WARNING[1886]: chan_dahdi.c:17278 process_dahdi: Ignoring any changes to 'hasmanager' (on reload) at line 47.
== Registered channel type 'DAHDI' (DAHDI Telephony Driver)
== Manager registered action DAHDITransfer
== Manager registered action DAHDIHangup
== Manager registered action DAHDIDialOffhook
== Manager registered action DAHDIDNDon
== Manager registered action DAHDIDNDoff
== Manager registered action DAHDIShowChannels
== Manager registered action DAHDIRestart
Loaded chan_dahdi.so => (DAHDI Telephony Driver)
```

In my extension.conf file i wrote dialplan for user so sandeep is jitsi user and 81 and 88 is landline number.

```
[general]
static=yes
writeprotect=no
clearglobalvars=no

[Incoming]
exten => s,1,Answer
exten => s,2,Dial(DAHDI/g1,20,rt)
exten => s,3,Voicemail(1000,u)
exten => s,103,Voicemail(1000,b)
exten => sandeep,1,Dial(SIP/sandeep)
exten => sandeep,n,Hangup()

exten => 1004,4,Dial(SIP/sandeep)
exten => 1004,n,Hangup()
; Testing extension, prepare to be insulted like a
; Monthy Python knight

exten => 81,1,Dial(DAHDI/1,20,rt)
exten => 81,n,Hangup()

exten => 88,1,Dial(DAHDI/1,20,rt)
exten => 88,n,Hangup()

exten => 8500,1,VoiceMailMain
exten => 8501,1,MusicOnHold
exten => _9.,1,Dial(DAHDI/g2/www${EXTEN:1})
exten => _9.,2,Congestion

exten => 201,1,Answer()
exten => 201,n,Playback(tt-monty-knights)
exten => 201,n,Hangup()

; Echo-test, it is good to test if we have sound in both directions.
; The call is answered
exten => 202,1,Answer()
; Welcome message is played
exten => 202,n,Playback(welcome)
; Play information about the echo test
exten => 202,n,Playback(demo-echotest)
; Do the echo test, end with the # key
exten => 202,n,Echo()
; Plays information that the echo test is done
exten => 202,n,Playback(demo-echodone)
; Goodbye message is played
exten => 202,n,Playback(vm-goodbye)
; Hangup() ends the call, hangs up the line
exten => 202,n,Hangup()
```

After loading extension and dahdi, i called from jitsi and dialed 81 but asterisk is giving o/p as below and  busy tone is coming on jitsi

```
-- Executing [81@myphones:1] Dial("SIP/sandeep-00000000", "DAHDI/1,20,rt") in new stack
-- Called 1
[Nov  2 14:45:31] WARNING[2145]: chan_dahdi.c:7536 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 1: Red Alarm
-- Hanging up on 'DAHDI/1-1'
-- Hungup 'DAHDI/1-1'
== Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)
-- Executing [81@myphones:2] Hangup("SIP/sandeep-00000000", "") in new stack
== Spawn extension (myphones, 81, 2) exited non-zero on 'SIP/sandeep-00000000'
```

Any help to resolve this problem.

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the FXO port isn't plugged in (or has low battery). It's showing RED ALARM which, on an analog FXO port, means the card could not detect the presence of the battery voltage provided by the telephone company.

Also, normally when you dial out through an FXO port you need to provide the digits that you want to dial. Like Dial(DAHDI/1/xxxx).

Comment: My problem got solved. battery voltage was not correct.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

My problem got solved. battery voltage was not correct.
Thanks a lot